# Await to AJAX call doen't work as expected

Tags: ajax, async-await

I have the following two functions:

```
function scan_request(address, file_url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        url: 'http://some_site/api/file/scan',       
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);//get json response and parse it
            $(json).each(function (i, val) {//extract data from json
                $.each(val, async function (key, value) {
                    if (key.toLowerCase() == "jobid") {
                        var result = await query_request();
                        alert("result:" + result);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}

async function query_request() {
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": 'http://some_site/api/file/query',
        "method": "POST"
    }
    var res;
    $.ajax(settings).then(function (response) {
        alert("response: " + response);
        res = response;
    });
    return res;
}
```

It first alerts `result: undefined`

and after it alerts: `response: [object Object]`

**But I'm expecting for:**

First alert `response: [object Object]`

And after alert `result: [object Object]`

It seems like it doesnt wait to the call: `var result = await query_request();` and therefore the result is undefined and the alert appears before the inner alert, what am I missing?

Comment: To address your question more directly (I suspect my post below is clear enough, but it does not spell it out): You get `result: undefined` because your function *does not return anything*. There is nothing to `await` and execution continues immetiately. At some point later, the `.then()` response handler kicks in and writes out `response: [object Object]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only `await` a promise. *(Or a function that returns a promise.)*

Your `query_request()` should return the promise that is created by `$.ajax()`. And since it does not need to await anything *itself*, it does not need to be marked as `async`.

```
// returns a promise, i.e. can be awaited in caller
function query_request(value) {
    return $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        url: 'http://some_site/api/file/query',
        method: "POST",
        data: {jobid: value}
    });
}
```

Now you can `await` the result of `query_request()` inside an `async` function:

```
$(json).each(function (i, val) {
    $.each(val, async function (key, value) {
        if (key.toLowerCase() == "jobid") {
            var result = await query_request(value);
            alert("result:" + result);
        }
    });
});
```

However, this code has a problem - it dasiy-chains the requests inside the loop, when they all could actually be running in parallel. This means it's slower than it needs to be.

Shifting the approach a bit, we can make sure that the Ajax requests are running in parallel instead of one after another:

```
async function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var todo = [], pending, results;

    // make a list of all the things we want to request
    $(json).each(async function (i, val) {
        $.each(val, function (key, value) {
            if (key.toLowerCase() == "jobid") todo.push(value);
        });
    });

    // request them all in parallel (=> array of promises)
    pending = todo.map(query_request);

    // wait for all of the results
    results = await Promise.all(pending)

    // ...now work with the results
}
```